# If I am NMS friends with both Bob and Alice, but they do not have each other's friend codes, will Bob see if I am in Alice's session?

Tags: no-mans-sky

If I join a friend's multiplayer session, will my other friend see that I'm in the first friend's lobby even though they haven't added each other on NMS?